# How to secure sensitive data during communicaiton on web app?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption

I've been reading about securing sensitive data while communicating with server. It all emphasise on encryption which make sense.

Let say I have a web page which authenticates user. At login section how do I transfer user password securely? Is SSL enough? If not then, should I perform encryption or hashing with javascript then transfer to the server?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There certainly could be *other* problems in any given codebase which make it less secure, but specifically in terms of encrypting data between the browser and the server to keep it away from 3rd party observers, that's exactly what SSL does.